# How do I select distinct ID when ID could have multiple values

Tags: sql

Aim: To find all properties where all ratings are not A to D

Issue: If a property has multiple ratings which are not A - D then these are still counted.

Code:

```
Select DISTINCT (PropertyID)
FROM TableA
WHERE Rating NOT BETWEEN 'A' AND 'D'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select PropertyID
FROM TableA
group by PropertyID
having sum(case when Rating IN ('A','B','C','D') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

If you want only the number of properties then put a count around that

```
select count(*) as property_count 
from
(
   select PropertyID from tableA ...
) alias_name
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me results of N/A and Unknown. What I want to get is the number of properties that do not have A,B,C or D. I think we are closer though. i.e. Table might have a property with two rows one with A and one with NA so should not be counted